# Why useState returns the opposite value instead of the value it was assign inside the onMouseDown and onMouseUp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am trying to build a navigation that works like a draggable slider on mobile but I have a problem.

When I try to stop the calculations on mouseup nothing really happens and the nav track still follows the mouse.

I have consoled logged the state that I used to check if the mouse is down or up and I noticed that the state value is the opposite value that it should be.

[image]

Here is the relevant code

```
  const [isDragStart, setIsDragStart] = useState(false);
  const [leftPos, setLeftPos] = useState(0);
  const [prevPageX, setPrevPageX] = useState(0);
  const [prevLeftPos, setPrevLeftPos] = useState(0);
  const [posDiff, setPosDiff] = useState(0);

  const track = useRef();

  const navTrack = track.current;

  const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    setIsDragStart(true);
    console.log('click down', isDragStart);
    setPrevPageX(e.pageX);
    setPrevLeftPos(navTrack.getBoundingClientRect().left);
  };

  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (isDragStart === false) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    setPosDiff(e.pageX - prevPageX);
    setLeftPos(prevLeftPos - posDiff);
  };

  const onMouseUp = (e) => {
    setIsDragStart(false);
    console.log('click up', isDragStart);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.nav}>
      <div
        className={`${styles.navContainer} ${
          openNav && styles.navContainerActive
        }`}
      >
        <div
          ref={track}
          className={styles.navTrack}
          style={{ left: leftPos }}
          onMouseMove={(e) => onMouseMove(e)}
          onMouseDown={(e) => onMouseDown(e)}
          onMouseUp={(e) => onMouseUp(e)}
        >
          {data.map((link, index) => (
            <a href='#' className={styles.link} key={link.title}>
              <h3 className={styles.linkTitle}>{link.title}</h3>
              <div className={styles.linkCard}></div>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: *"Why useState returns the opposite value instead of the value it was assign inside the onMouseDown and onMouseUp"* because `setIsDragStart` is asynchronous and `isDragStart` won't change untill the next render. Sidenote: constants generally don't change their value very often ;)

Comment: ohh, so in this case would be better to use a let? I am trying to avoid them.

Comment: No @Oliver, the most relevant part was that about the variable not updating until the next render! No matter what! Besides that, apart from the `console.log`s showing an outdated state, the code should work IMO.